# How can I efficiently select the most recent record from dependent table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is what I do, which works but is painfully slow. I need to optimize it.

```
SELECT main_table.id
FROM main_table
INNER JOIN linked_table latest_linked_record ON latest_linked_record.id = (
       SELECT clever_alias.id
       FROM linked_table clever_alias
       WHERE clever_alias.claim_order_id = main_table.id
       ORDER BY clever_alias.updated_at DESC,
                clever_alias.id DESC
       LIMIT 1
)
WHERE latest_linked_record.some_column NOT IN (1, 19)
```

It seems I've been battling with this for my entire life, with MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle and Postgres alike. Apart from strategies like materialized views, is there anything I can do to improve performance?

Comment: Maybe using `LATERAL JOIN`

Comment: there are several faster ways. the fastest solution depends on undisclosed details of your setup. postgres version, table definitions, relevant indexes, data distribution.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, I would recommend `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT mt.id
FROM main_table mt INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (lt.claim_order_id) lt.*
      FROM linked_table lt
      ORDER BY lt.claim_order_id, lt.claim_order_id DESC, lt.id DESC
     ) lt
     ON lt.claim_order_id = mt.id
WHERE lt.some_column NOT IN (1, 19);
```

Of course, for this query, the `JOIN` is not necessary:

```
SELECT lt.claim_order_id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (lt.claim_order_id) lt.*
      FROM linked_table lt
      ORDER BY lt.claim_order_id, lt.claim_order_id DESC, lt.id DESC
     ) lt
WHERE lt.some_column NOT IN (1, 19);
```